# I am facing Wordpress Redirection Hack on my WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress

I have facing redirection hack in my WordPress website someone changed my site url.. how it is possible for someone to change site url without getting WordPress Access.

Answer (score 0):

by modifying one of the files on your server, e.g. your .htaccess file, wp-config.php or pretty much any other you can think of. Admin access is not necessary.

Comment: I added Wordfence plugin and its fixed .. Thanks for your Reply.